# This method 'Scaffold' isn't defined for the type 'MyApp'

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I have reinstalled the flutter and Android Studio to my device and after that Scaffold widget is not working. It says "This method 'Scaffold' isn't defined for the type 'MyApp' "

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code you have

Comment: Same as @MendelG please show your code.

Answer (score 1):

add wrap **Scaffold** with **MaterialApp** widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: const Center(
          child: Text('Hello World'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I am doing the same thing. This issues arrises with latest version of flutter 3.0.5. When I roll back to old version of flutter 3.0.2 it works fine